# Error when running application with PowerShell version 7: "Get-ExecutionPolicy" command not found

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-core, powershell-7.0, executionpolicy

Description:

I encountered an error while running my application with PowerShell version 7. The error message states:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy: The 'Get-ExecutionPolicy' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Security'."

At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ExecutionPolicy;
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ExecutionPolicy:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

I would like to know how to resolve this issue and understand the possible cause of the error.

Additional Details:

I have successfully run the application using PowerShell version 5 without any errors. However, when I switch to PowerShell version 7, I encounter this specific error. I have already attempted to resolve it by using the command `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Security` in an administrative setting, but it still showing the same error, I also tried `Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Security` but it is also dropping an error while installing that. I also referred to the Microsoft documentation on importing modules (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7.3#description), but the issue persists.

Comment: When you tried `Import-Module`, what does "it did not work" mean? Is there an error message?

Comment: So run `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Security` and see what happens. Maybe you need `Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Security` if that module is not installed in order to import/load. Once you do that, then the `Get-ExecutionPolicy` should work from what that error message indicates. To be a little more specific to the previous comment, try that and post with an [edit] for additional clarity.

Comment: I did the required changes, also `Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Security` is not working as it dropping error.

Comment: The error I ecnoutner while install module is :

`Install-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security'. Try
Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
`